# Load SCons Tool via absolute path

Tags: scons

I have a SCons Tool, which works when I put `mytool.py` and `__init__.py` under `site_scons/site_tools/mytool`.

Now I would like change it to rather be referenced via an absolute path from somewhere else.

So I called it via:

```
mytoolpath = '/tools/mytool'
env = Environment(tools=['mytool'], toolpath=mytoolpath)
```

and it excepts with `EnvironmentError: No tool named 'mytool': not a Zip file:`

`mytool.py` is located in `/tools/mytool` so I really do not understand where the problem is. Could someone shed some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is one of the few places, where strings are not upconverted to lists.
So you have to invoke this via:

```
env = Environment(tools=['mytool'], toolpath=[mytoolpath])
```